# Fourier Cosine series of $f(t)$

Tags: calculus

Consider the following function defined on the interval $[0,\pi]$:

$f(t) = 8t$ when $t$ is less than or equal to 0 or less than $\pi/2$.
$f(t)$ is also equal to $8\pi-8t$ when $t$ is greater than or equal to $\pi/2$ and less than or equal to $\pi$.

The Fourier cosine series of $f(t)$ is

$f(t)=a_0/2 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k \cos kt$

What is $a_k= $ when $k=4n+2$ for some $n$?

I tried using the cosine series formula but I got a very horrible looking and wrong equation on wolfram-alpha. Please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your function's definition. $F(t) = 8t$ when $t \leq 0$ or $t \leq \pi/2$? Do you mean $F(t) = 8t$ when $t \in [0, \pi/2)$? And then $8\pi-8t$ for $t \in [\pi/2, \pi]$? In that case, 
\begin{align}
a_n &= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2} f(x)\cos(nx) dx\\
 \pi a_n &= \int_0^{\pi} 8x\cos(nx) dx + \int_\pi^{\pi/2} (8\pi - 8x)\cos(nx) dx + ...\\
&= 8x\sin(nx)|^{\pi/2}_0 dx -\frac{8}{n} \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(nx) dx + ...\\
 &= \frac{\pi}{n}\sin(n\pi/2) + 8/n^2\cos(n\pi/2) + ... 
\end{align}
I left the other integral for you. So far, when you plug in $n = 4k+2$, you seem to get 0 from the $\sin$ and $(-1)^n$ from $\cos$.

Comment: Your assumption is right but the answer of (-1)^n for the cos isn't/  The other answer for sin is though.